# Page.MaxPageStateFieldLength and ViewState Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, viewstate

I was recently looking at my web.config and pulled up the MSDN page about `Page.MaxPageStateFieldLength` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maxpagestatefieldlength.aspx

The default is set to `-1` meaning that the _VIEWSTATE field will be continuously written to on the page in a large chunk.

Are there any performance benefits to splitting it up into chunks (i.e. setting the property to a positive number)? There is massive ViewState data on a single page of our site using a Telerik `RadScheduler` control that people complain about slowness.

Pages are already gzipped and ViewState is turned off where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There aren't performance benefits to split viewstate.

When ViewState in your page become very large it can be a problem as some firewalls, antiviruses and proxies will prevent access to pages containing such huge ViewState sizes.

For this purpose ASP.NET 2.0 introduces the ViewState Chunking mechanism.